# Obtener como variable el estado de un checkbox para pasarla por url - Javascript/JQery

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, checkbox

recien empiezo con esto de PHP, HTML, javascript, Jquery y estoy haciendo un proyecto y necesito que pase por url el estado de un checkbox para abrir en otra pagina y validar segun el estado de ese checkbox. JQuery y javascript no lo manejo muy bien, como se ve. Por lo que necesitaria ayuda. Aclaro no utilizo un formulario, es un listado de una consulta donde por cada item puedo imprimir un recibo. En acciones recibo desde ahi abro un popup con el recibo usando el codigo que pegue debajo y por eso uso la etiqueta "< a >".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el script que logre hacerlo funcionar pero me lo muestra en un input o en un alert y lo que necesito es que se guarde en una variable para poder utilizarla con codigo PHP.

```
<script>
    $(document).on('change','input[type="checkbox"]' ,function(e) {
    if(this.id=="firma") {
        if(this.checked) $('#firma1').val(this.value);
        else $('#firma1').val("2");
    }
});
</script>

<body>
    <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="firma" name ="firma">
    
    <input type="text" name="firma1" id="firma1">
</body>
```

Asi es como lo deberia enviar, la variable seria $onoff

```
<a href="recibo.php?onoff=<?php echo $onoff;?>" target="_blank" onclick="window.open(this.href,this.target,'width=770,height=400,top=150,left=150,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no, toolbar=no, directories=no');return false;">Recibo</a>
```

Despues tomo el valor de onoff con GET y lo valido con un if

```
$onoff = $_GET['onoff'];
if($onoff == 1){
ejecuto codigo
}
```

Comment: Crea un formulario con método _GET_ y el _checkbox_ se va a agregar automáticamente si está marcado.

Answer (score 0):

No deberias usar nunca un elemento `<a>` para ese proposito, ya que los formularios son y deberian ser los encargados de enviar informacion a otra pagina, tu en su lugar estarias abriendo otra ventana con ciertos datos, pero aparentemente lo estas haciendo de manera erronea, puesto que la `URL` que presentas seria incorrecta:

```
href="recibo.php?id=onoff=<?php echo $onoff;?>"
```

Si, se que esto es valido si es un archivo `.php`, pero el formato de `URL` es invalido,  puesto que aparentemente estas intentando asignar a una variable **2 valores**, lo cual es **imposible**:

```
id=onoff=<?php echo $onoff;?>
```

En esa parte se ve mas concretamente tu error.

Lo segundo es que si deseas enviar informacion a otra `URL`, que pasa cuando es la primera vez que lo haces?, pues el resultado es que la variable `$onoff`, no tiene contenido, o tendra el contenido por default definido en el archivo `PHP`, asi que esta linea de aqui:

```
<?php echo $onoff;?>
```

Enrealidad seria como imprimir un string vacio, o en caso de que de inicios tenga algun valor pues imprimira ese valor, lo cual muchas veces no se correspondera con la informacion que tu deseabas que fuera dinamica.

Muy bien, entonces ahora que te he dicho los errores, te hare las siguientes propuestas:

- Elimina el elemento `<a>`, no deberias usar ese elemento para postear cosas.
- Encerrar tus inputs en un formulario y crear un boton de submit para poder enviar los datos.
- Colocarle un `name` a cada input el cual deseas que su informacion sea enviada, pues el campo `name` describira atributos importantes de la `URL`.

Entonces haciendo los cambios parte de tu `HTML` deberia quedar asi:

```
<body>
    <form action = "recibo.php" method = "GET">
      <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="firma" name ="firma">
    
      <input type="text" name="firma1" id="firma1">
      <button type = "submit">Enviar!</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

Y  por el lado de php en el archivo **recibo.php**, recibirias los datos asi:

```
$firma = $_GET['firma'];
$firma1 = $_GET['firma1'];
```

Creo que se te fueron un poco las pinzas en el codigo `PHP`, pues teoricamente tu nunca estabas enviando un atributo llamado `onof`, de hecho nisiquiera estabas enviando nada, puesto que la `URL` era incorrecta, en su lugar ahora debes hacer esas comprobaciones y usos en `PHP` pero con los nombres correctos que se envian.

En este caso `firma` y `firma1`, ya que no hay ningun input con el `name` onof en tu `HTML`.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responderme, ahi corregi el error del id=onoff= (href="recibo.php?id=onoff=<?php echo $onoff;?>") y no lo puse pero no utilizo un formulario, es un listado de una base de datos donde genero un recibo por cada item y el recibo lo genero de esa forma, ahora veo si puedo agregar una foto del formulario o algo. Tambien soy nuevo aca y no estoy muy acostumbrado a escribir y pegar codigo, jajajaja!!!

Comment: @Martin, de todas maneras recuerda que no es bueno usar un elemento `<a>` para ese proposito, aunque esta bien que lo hayas corregido, una cosa mas, si mi respuesta te ayudo o si directamente resolvio tu problema, puedes dar la respuesta como aceptada dandole al boton que parece un chulo.

Comment: Hola, no me sirvio ya que de tu forma lo se utilizar y como no es un form ahi me complico, fijate que puse una imagen de como es una parte del listado donde envio ese codigo. NO se como sacar afuera ese valor y pasarlo por url sin usar un formulario.

Comment: La pregunta es, porque no usar un formulario?, los formularios son especializados en el transporte de datos, tu problema aparentemente es que los valores que intentas recolectar no son adecuados (no los estas obteniendo de la forma correcta), es un problema de parte de `jQuery` y el codigo javascript que tienes, tu no puedes acceder a `this`, porque en ese caso `'input[type="checkbox"]'`, haria parte de una coleccion de elementos `HTML` y no de un solo elemento, y pues la coleccion en si no tiene las propiedades que intentas sacar de `jQuery`.

Comment: Por cierto usar una etiqueta `<a>` para postear datos se considera una mala practica de seguridad, es por eso que se debe evitar usar elementos `<a>`, pues si requieres abrir una ventana nueva existe el atributo `target = "blank"`, creo que tambien es aplicable a los `form`.

Comment: Por cierto, donde esta el alert que mencionas?, donde intentas guardar esa informacion?, que valor en especifico intentas sacar?, hace falta codigo relevante.

Comment: no lo agregue porque fue con otra prueba, este me habia parecido mas sencillo pero la verdad toco de oido, no la tengo muy claro y con todo estoy recien empezando. No sabia que esa etiqueta era mala practica de seguridad, voy a ver como modificarlo. El tema es que al no tenerlo muy claro no me doy cuenta de momento como enviar todos los parametros como lo hacia por url. Cada fila de la tabla debe enviar parametros diferentes, por lo menos lo habia hecho asi. por ahi lo estoy haciendo mal. Poner todo el codigo completo me parece no se justifica ya que son 250 lineas y no esta pulido del todo.

Comment: @Martin, cierto no se debe poner todo el codigo, pero si el minimo relevante y que describes para la pregunta, por ejemplo, la parte donde dices usas el `alert` que te provee la informacion que necesitas, o la forma en la que intentas guardar esa informacion, si necesitas enviar informacion de toda una tabla es aconsejable trabajar mas bien con ajax y hacer una extraccion de datos de forma recursiva, asi como su envio. por ejemplo la forma mas comoda de poder enviar esa cantidad de datos ordenada es mediante `JSON`.

Comment: PD: el elemento `<a>` no es aconsejable solo para ese tipo de cosas (posteo de informacion), en su lugar solo deberia ser usado como link para redirigir al usuario a una pagina en plano, (sin pasarle parametros por URL), mas no quiere decir que deberias dejar de usar el elemento `<a>`, puesto que es indispensable para otras cosas. solo no lo uses para pasar informacion.